# How to out the output of the command 'cal' to csv.?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv, cal

How can I format the output of the command `cal -y 2020` as a csv? I want to  prepare the calendar in a table processor. Can this be done?

I am using Slackware 14.2.

Comment: What output? Just one month? `cal -3`? Maybe `cal -Y`? Which `cal`? Are you on Linux? MacOS? BSD? Something else? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Slackware is a Linux distribution.

Comment: @Soruk yes, thank you, I am aware of that :) That was only added after I commented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
 cal 2020  | sed 's/ \([0-9]\) /\1 /g;s/ \([0-9]\)$/\1/g;s/ /,/g;s/,,,/,/g' > 2020.csv
```